# Drush css-js cache clear error

Tags: drush

There are times when I run `drush cc css-js` and I get the following error:

'css-js' cache is not a valid cache type

Does anyone know why this may happen?

Thanks,

Comment: You're probably running it outside of a Drupal root, and without specifying a @site to run it on. So Drush tries to clear its internal cache, in which there's no 'css-js' type. To test: `cd /path/to/drupal/root; drush cc css-js; cd ..; drush cc css-js`. The first `cc` call should work, but not the second

Comment: Clive's answer above is correct. I added an issue to the Drush queue for this: http://drupal.org/node/1954552

Comment: Please provide more information here. What is the output of drush status, and what happens when you run with --debug?

Answer (score 1):

The latest dev releases of Drush (both 8.x-6.x and 7.x-5.x) now provide a better error message when attempting to select a specific cache type (e.g. css-js) without first selecting a working Drupal site.  c.f. http://drupal.org/node/1954552

Note also that when selecting a Drupal site, `cd /path/to/drupal/root` only works if settings.php is stored in a directory called "default".  Otherwise, you will need to instead `cd /path/to/drupal/root/sites/mysite.com` before using drush cc css-js.  You can also use the --root and --uri parameters, e.g. `drush --root=/path/to/drupal/root --uri=http://mysite.com cc css-js`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   I took another look at my alias for clearing the cache and I am passing the root.

drush -r /srv/examplesite/htdocs/ cc css-js  

and my settings.php file is in the default folder.